# Group By Query giving error when i sum up a selected field

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum

I have a query like this, here pendingQty is decimal? All is going well except for the last line:

```
select newGroup.Sum()
```

Original query:

```
var qty = from orders in lstPendingQty
           where orders.SoId == 5
           group new { orders.PendingQty } 
                 by orders.SoId into newGroup
           select newGroup.Sum()
```

It is giving me some implicit conversion error.

Comment: Why you need groupby ?

Comment: Because i have multiple SOId's and i want to sum up their PendigQty's.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `sum()` function to the result:

```
var qty = (from orders in lstPendingQty
           where orders.SoId == 5
           group new { orders.PendingQty } 
           by orders.SoId into newGroup
           select newGroup).Sum()
```